# How to improve MySQL Query Performance in Codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, performance, codeigniter

I have this MySQL query which I am loading in to my home controller and after running Codeigniter's `$searchterm = $this->search_model->searchterm_handler($this->input->get_post('searchterm', TRUE));`
I get an execution time of `0.7110`

The Query inside my model:

```
<?php
class Search_Model extends CI_Model

    public function search($searchterm,$limit)
        {
            $sql = "SELECT cast(s.req_date as Date) as Date, SUM(s.sTransaction)+SUM(r.rTransaction) as SUMt, SUM(s.sSuccess)+ SUM(r.rSuccess) as SUMs, s.sTransaction, r.rTransaction, s.sSuccess, r.rSuccess
                    FROM
                    (SELECT s.req_date, COUNT(*) as sTransaction, SUM(s.status = 0) as sSuccess 
                    FROM transaction_log_ats_201503 as s WHERE cast(s.req_date as time) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '$searchterm'
                    GROUP BY cast(req_date as Date) desc) as s 
                    JOIN
                    (SELECT r.req_date, COUNT(*) as rTransaction, SUM(r.status = 0) as rSuccess 
                    FROM transaction_log_atr_201503 as r WHERE cast(r.req_date as time) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '$searchterm'
                    GROUP BY cast(req_date as Date) desc) as r 
                    ON cast(s.req_date as date)=cast(r.req_date as date)
                    GROUP BY Date desc";


            $q = $this->db->query($sql);
            if($q->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                foreach($q->result() as $row)
                {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
                return $data;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
 ?>
```

Is there any posibble way to increase query performance?

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to redesign your query so it doesnt use the nested select statements and relys just on joins. Then you will need to add index's to the fields you are using for your joins.

Comment: Can you show me how to use INDEX in this situation? thanks

Comment: Not without knowing your table structure. First thing is to redesign your query to get rid of the nested select statements. Its likely it will perform better if you split it into several queries and relate the data in php. Indexing is a broad topic but not that complicated concept. Do some reading you will find lots of tutorials on the subject

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a ")".

Why have `DESC` in the subqueries; it does not control anything useful.

MySQL (until 5.6) cannot optimize
`FROM ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ...`
There are no indexes, so it does full table scans on the tmp tables, thereby being quite slow.

Possible solutions:

- Upgrade to 5.6.
- Put one of the subqueries in a `TEMPORARY` table and give it an INDEX on `reg_date`.

Comment: How to use INDEX in MYSQL? I dont understand INDEX function..I have read about INDEX function but im not fully understand.

Comment: Big topic.  `INDEX` is not a "function"; it is an attribute of a table.  It is very important for performance.  Imagine being a clerk and having a thousand pieces of paper (one resume/application/etc per person) and needing to find the paper from me.  Now imagine having stacked neatly in alphabetical order.  That's the difference an INDEX makes.